# Phonegap rede wifi

Tags: apache-cordova

Existe um modo de recuperar as informações da rede que o device está conectado?

Gostaria de mandar para o webservice a rede onde o device está conectado.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information